# How can I remove my name from installation message?

Tags: android

When installation starts It says "Appname by my name" Do you want to Install or not ?
I don't want to  show to the users my name. How and where to edit and change it to some other name ? How and where to edit ? It should not show my original name.

Comment: Open your string.xml and check what value it contains for `app_name` variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Your name is stored in a key using which you've signed the app.
If the app is not published yet, create a new key that doesn't contain your name.
Note that once published, the key must not be changed. If you loose or change your key you woun't be able to publish new updates.

[Signing Your Applications | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: But I remember that I did not used my name in key generation while signing the app.